# Where is an Example Spring Security OAuth2 Client Configuration using XML for Authorization Code?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Where can I find an basic applicationContext.xml configuration of an OAuth2 Client for Authorization Code grant type using spring-security-oauth2 version 2.0.x ?

Comment: can you share your complete xml configuration file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample in the integration tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/xml/client/src/main/resources/context.xml. The old 1.0.* XML should work with 2.0.* as well, so just look at the tonr2 sample in the 1.0.x branch.